# PHP Bash Script bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: php, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkins pipeline I am ruuning the php bash script. Sometimes it works but sometimes it throws error bad interpreter: No such file or directory. This error comes when jenkins build referes to the tmp branch directory. Does any one know why its happening. I have attached the screenshot too[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eobu9.png)

Comment: Should it be `/tmp...` ? - another common source of bad interpreter is the ^M eol on non-windows machines.  May need to see the `script.sh` .

Comment: this is the php script #!/usr/bin/php
<?php

echo"PHP ENV detected found"
?>

Comment: it works fine when running with master agent but doesnt work when running with some other agent

Comment: in other agent the reference branch is like this branchname@tmp. while in master agent its only branchname. I guess tmp folder created by jenkins for branch in workspace is the issue